# Can you set events within Tab Control for MS Access?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have been searching the internet for this all day. But no luck.

Can you setup events for when you enter/leave a tab.

I.E.

```
OnExit(Tab1)
Do something
```

Thanks

Comment: Tabs are a means of ordering controls and only have a limted range of events, there are nearly always workarounds. What exactly d you want to do?

Comment: I want to restrict the user from leaving the tab unless a certain combo box is selected. i.e. OnExit of tab, If combobox1 is null, don't let them leave, else do nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your program flow, you might try:

```
Private Sub Combo3_Exit(Cancel As Integer)
    If IsNull(Me.Combo3) Then
        MsgBox "No exit"
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Current()
    Me.Combo3.SetFocus
    ''Or to refer to a subform from the main form
    Me.subformcontrolname.Form.Combo3.SetFocus
End Sub
```

Does the tab contain a subform or only controls from the main form?

A subform has an Exit event, so if you are only concerned that once you have entered the subform you should not leave without completing data, you could:

```
Private Sub subformcontrolname_Exit(Cancel As Integer)
    If IsNull(Me.subformcontrolname.Form.Combo3) Then
        Me.subformcontrolname.Form.Combo3.SetFocus
        MsgBox "No exit"
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Anton, if you have a subform, you have a lot more options, just a minute.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! you answered my question....Having other issues with tab control. After that message gets output and I just move tabs, it doesn't keep me in the same tab...:(

Comment: I cannot replicate the problem. Are you using the second code sample with exit for a subform? Is the subform a continuous form?

Answer (score 0):

While this is not exactly what you want, you could instead of handling the exit simply prevent the user from clicking somewhere else. To do this, attach some code to your combobox1 that bascially set `.Enabled=X`for all elements outside your tab view - where `X` is determined by the state of the combobox...